# Creating a directory inside a virtualenv via virtualenvwrapper's postmkvirtualenv

Tags: bash, shell, virtualenv

Inside every virtualenv of mine, I add a directory named `run`, this is where i put running pid files and logs, etc. I noticed that postmkvirtualenv can help me make sure this always happens when I create a new virtualenv but im not sure how to implement. I would say `mkdir $VIRTUAL_HOME/$VIRTUALENV/run` but `$VIRTUALENV` is not available... I know it's possible, just not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` variable instead.

Example `postmkvirtalenv`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir "${VIRTUAL_ENV}"/run
```

The variable is quoted to protect against spaces in the path.